# Android Studio -- code completion order screwy?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, code-completion

Can anybody tell me if there's a way to modify Android Studio's presentation order for code completion?

Writing Dart / Flutter code and whenever I want to `print()` something to the console, the `print()` function is second in the list (behind `Icons.print`, of all freaking things) and I am constantly forgetting and having to undo and step down one place in the list.

[image]

It's terribly inconvenient and frustrating. There is another example that constantly drives me batty too, but I cannot remember what it is right now. Would be wonderful if there were a way to modify this in some way.

Thank you in advance, for saving my sanity!

Comment: Hey @ConleeC did you found a solution? I also develop in Flutter/Dart and experience the same "issue".